# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Interpersonal Skills's [first pro tempore moderator election](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: avazula]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5526120231337984/0).

Answer (score 14):

Congrats Avazula!! Welcome to moderating, we're glad to have you on the team!

And shouts out to the other candidates for making it hard to rank my votes - I'm looking forward to seeing the site continue to grow with all of you :)

Comment: It was really hard to choose who to vote for, indeed! Thank you Em C.

Answer (score 12):

Congrats Avazula, I'm sure you'll make an excellent moderator and I'm excited to see you join the team.

Comment: Looking forward to reviewing your flags :) Thank you Rainbacon.

Answer (score 12):

Congrats avazula, I know you will be an amazing mod!

Comment: Thank you Ælis, I'm counting on you to provide us our daily batch of posts to review :D

Comment: @avazula Be careful with what you wish, I might decide to ask a highly controversial vegan question who will then hit HNQ :p

Answer (score 11):

Avazula has always had an upbeat, friendly attitude going into every interaction on the site I've seen. I can't help but imagine her smiling whenever I read one of her comments/messages.

I know you'll make a wonderful mod, Ava, and I can't wait to see what you do for the site with your new mod abilities!!

Comment: Now beware to anyone I'll draw if they don't choose my drawing as their profile picture! Haha. Thanks Scohe, and thanks for everything you're doing for the site.

Answer (score 11):

**Congratulations Avazula!!!** It's really good to have you on board! Your cleaning tools await you. Please get started at your convenience.

[image: fork shovel]

And thank you all for volunteering. There was a great pool of candidates.

Comment: Can I use a broom? I'm not a fan of rakes :p Thank you AJ!

Comment: No! You gotta use what SE gives you! :P Welcome! :)

Comment: @avazula: actually, there are only 2 places where you can see a man with a broom. 1. my home 2. Hogwarts :D (wait! you ain't a boy?! jeez... miss it! ^-^)

Comment: @OldPadawan Actually [I'm an aircraft](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47691890#47691890) :D

Comment: @AJ how have you been a mod this long without knowing about all the mod-created improvements to the tools?  Avazula is certainly allowed to transform the rake into a broom, but when SE changes something in the backend that breaks the handle, it'll also be her problem to fix. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, sure! She can! She can also turn it into a mop to polish things if she wants. ;P

Comment: Be careful with mops; the water's rate-limited. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I knew you would **win**.  IPS is lucky to have you!